# How to use joins in a mysql query across three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, many-to-many

at first my tables:

```
+----------+      +--------------+     
| users    |      | users_groups |     +--------------+
+----------+      +--------------+     | groups       |
| user_id  |----->| user_id      |     +--------------+
| username |      | group_id     |<----| group_id     |
| realname |      +--------------+     | group_name   |
| password |                           | group_desc   |
+----------+                           +--------------+
```

From an other PHP script I have a variable `$group_id` and now I want all usernames and user_ids which are in this group (`$group_id`).

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE users_groups.group_id = $group_id
```

How should the query look like? Something with joins, isn't it?

My PHP-Code:

```
$group_id = $_POST["group_id"];

    $query_user = mysqli_query($db, 
                                    "SELECT 
                                    User.user_id, User.username
                                    FROM users User 
                                    INNER JOIN user_groups UserGroup
                                        ON User.user_id = UserGroup.user_id
                                    WHERE UserGroup.group_id = $group_id
                                    ");
    while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_object($query_user)) {
        echo'
        '.$row_user->username.'<br>
        ';
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it should have joins.  Perhaps you should read about MySQL join syntax.  Google knows how to find it.

Comment: It won't solve your problem but I recommend you to use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    User.user_id, User.username
FROM users User 
INNER JOIN users_groups UserGroup
    ON User.user_id = UserGroup.user_id
WHERE UserGroup.group_id = $group_id
```

Hopefully this would work fine!

**EDIT:**

```
$group_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["group_id"]);

    $query_user = mysqli_query($db, 
                                    "SELECT 
                                    User.user_id, User.username
                                    FROM users User 
                                    INNER JOIN users_groups UserGroup
                                        ON User.user_id = UserGroup.user_id
                                    WHERE UserGroup.group_id = '$group_id'
                                    ");
    while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_object($query_user)) {
        echo $row_user->username.'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: I used your code with:
`while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_object($query_user)) {
   echo'
   '.$row_user->username.'<br>
   ';
  }` and it did not work. Error: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...

Comment: post your php code, it says `$query_user` is not type of `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: try now, verify that you are getting groupId in key `group_id`

Comment: there was a typo in table name, fixed now `user_groups` to `users_groups`, verify that all the table names in query have actual name.

Comment: re `mysql_real_escape_string`, you need to pass db connection .. answer updated respectively!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE users_groups.group_id = $group_id && users_groups.user_id = u.user_id
```